# Run Excel Function From Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an excel command button which simply copies the contents of one sheet to another. I am trying to run this command from within access. I do not get an error, however when I run the code from access, the information is not copied in excel. The code is below. Any ideas?

'

```
Private Sub Command92_Click()
 Dim x2 As Object
 Dim GetDBPath As String
 GetDBPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Reports.xlsm"

Set x2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

x2.Workbooks.Open (GetDBPath)

x2.Visible = True

x2.Run CommandButton1_Click
x2.ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)

x2.Quit

Set x2 = Nothing


End Sub'
```

Answer (score 1):

Run takes the name of a routine to run, as a String. You will also need to include the code name of the worksheet in the call:

```
x2.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
x2.Run "Sheet1.CommandButton1_Click"
```

for example.

Comment: After adding the quotes, a Run-time error appears saying the macro cannot be ran. Is that x2.run will only run macros and not functions/subs?

Comment: I did. I however se where 'enable all macros is disabled' and greyed out, so Im working on fixing that. Any ideas though? Excel 2013

Comment: Thanks. The following error is reported: Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range

Comment: I wouldn't say its a macro, its a sub I created that is ran from a command button. However, it runs ok in excel itself

Comment: Well I can't see how the code above could produce an error 9, so it must be the macro in Excel.